# a function calling itself periodically until condition, but loops quickly to crash

Tags: javascript, recursion, nested

I am attempting to build a function that checks periodically an indefinite number of variables, and if they are all false, does something.

The function should "return" when the conditions are met, and call itself otherwise every x ms.

Here I use a setTimeout for the function to call itself, with a long delay to attempt to avoid quick loop and crash. But for some reason the function calls itself right away. It does so many times, crashing the browser (and actually my OS a few times).

I seem to be in lack of some basic understanding of how the nesting function progresses.

As it is now, the function loops and crashes, beware.

The offending line is at the end of function checkIf(), there is the setTimeout that calls the function itself again.

The variables the function looks for are "users[i].listening", if you want to simulate meeting the conditions, change them both to false.

```
// *****DO NOT RUN THIS CODE, IT LOOPS/CRASHES BROWSERS 
// *****************************************************

users = [{user:"11", listening: "true"},{user:"22", listening:"false"}];

function checkIf(){
    var falses = 0; // We assume there are no users with listening = "false" yet
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) { // for each user
          if(users[i].listening == "false"){ // if its listening is "false"
              falses++; //+1 to var falses   
              if (falses == users.length){ // && if all user's listening are false
                  userDo(); // launch the action
                  return true; // get out of checkIf()
              } 
          } 
     } 

     //THIS SEEMS TO BE WHAT CAUSES THE LOOP/CRASH >>>>
     setTimeout(checkIf(), 4000); //otherwise repeat every 4 seconds 
}

function userDo(){ //this function makes those users do stuff
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        console.log("user " + users[i].user +" do this or that");
    }
}

checkIf(); //launch the checking function for the first time
```

Here the fiddle (with some console.log for debugging)

https://jsfiddle.net/r1jo84jm/1/

Thanks for reading, and your help.

Comment: `setTimeout(checkIf(), 4000);` remove the `()` - that _executes_ your function immediately - without it, `setTimeout` gets a reference to the function and it'd be run after the specified delay.

Comment: Is the recursion necessary? Couldn't you put the timeout function outside 'checkIf()`? I don't see any scope issue.

Comment: vlaz, thank you I did not know that!

Comment: @TecBrat there isn't any recursion as long as OP uses `setTimeout` correctly. Putting it _after_ the function means that it will be called once, not repeatedly.

Comment: TecBrat, could you please ellaborate what you mean, maybe with an example. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout()`? When the end condition is met, call `clearInterval()`.

Comment: @vlaz would you like to submit an answer so I can accept it ? your answer was on point in relation to my question indeed. thank you

Comment: @Barmar could you please elaborate on the benefits of using setInterval instead of setTimeout? thank you

Comment: @JaumeMal I don't think there is a need for an official answer - it was essentially just a typo. As for `setInterval` - it's pretty much the same as `setTimeout` but it will run the function every `delay` amount specified instead of once `clearInterval` is used to stop the function from being called. [Check MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) for the usage -

Comment: @vlaz ok, thank you.

Comment: @vlaz, how about if I have to call the function with the same arguments that it has been called before. In that case, within the setTimeout I do have to write the function with its arguments, But it seems then it is also fired rigth away: setTimeout( function(a,b,c), 4000)

Comment: @JaumeMal you can use `setTimeout(func, 4000, a, b, c)` - all arguments after the second one are passed to the function. Alternatively, you can make a new anonymous one `setTimeout(function() { func(a, b, c)}, 4000)`.

Comment: @vlaz thank you, I had found the second option, although I am curious about why the function invocation "functionname()" does not fire right away when enclosed within an anonymous function within setTimeout. Do you want to explain? maybe in an answer, this differences when calling a function in a recursive scenario or give me a hint on what to read? I think that it was more than a typo since I did not know or understand this differences. Maybe I can answer myself. Thanks again

Comment: @JaumeMal Quite simple, really - if you have `function() { otherFunction()}` then that anonymous function you've defined is not executed immediately. It acts as if you've done `var temp = function() { otherFunction()}; setTimeout(temp)` - only without ever creating that variable. The reason is that you are just passing a function reference to `setTimeout`. If it's not clear, then I'll write up an answer to showcase it better - unfortunately, I'm short on time right now, I will be able to post a better explanation in a few hours.

Comment: @vlaz ok, that is fine, thank you very much for your explanation